# Why closed points of a variety are Zariski dense?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I was told that closed points are Zariski dense in the variety by my teacher. But I don't understand what does it mean. Every single point in a variety is closed in Zariski topology because it's the zero locus of a maximal ideal. So how could I understand this statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed points are dense in $\operatorname{Spec} A$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250192/closed-points-are-dense-in-operatornamespec-a)

Comment: @Crostul I'm not sure it's very helpful to just close this question as a duplicate -- there's a fundamental misunderstanding in the question (not all points of a variety are closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that "every single point in a variety is closed in the Zariski topology". Look at the variety $\mathbb{A}^1 = \operatorname{Spec} \Bbbk[x]$. The generic point corresponding to the zero ideal $(0) \subset \Bbbk[x]$ is not closed. However the set of all closed points of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is dense for the Zariski topology (meaning that its closure is all of $\mathbb{A}^1$). See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/615709/10014) for a reference (an algebraic variety is in particular of finite type).

Comment: So that means the set of all closed points is dense. But how could we prove it?

Comment: @IntoksLiobein See the link I provided (I updated my answer to include a better one).

Comment: I see, the union of all closed point correspond to the intersection of all maximal ideals.

Comment: But I totally don't understand what is a scheme.

Comment: @IntoksLiobein What do you call a variety then...?

Comment: What I mean is affine variety which is a closed set in zariski.topology, that's actually all what I know.

Comment: @IntoksLiobein So you mean a closed set inside $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbbk[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ for some field $\Bbbk$ and some integer $n$?